# How to store XML tag values in database using Java?

Tags: java, database

I have written a code to read an xml file without specifying tagnames. I have used getElementBytagname(*) which reads every tag and give me output.

But now I want to insert those tag values in database columns. For eg. Suppose I have a tagname `<merchantId>101</merchantId>` this value need to be stored in database column name as merchantId.

Comment: So what exactly is your question? How to insert into database? Or how to extract the value out of the DOM parser result (see first answer)? Or...?

Answer (score 0):

Function `document.getElementsByTagName()` is returning list of nodes(`NodeList`).
From `NodeList` you can iterate to get all of the nodes inside 
`Node node = nodeListVar.item(indexOfNode)`
and get you data:

```
Element element = (Element) node;
System.out.println(element.getElementsByTagName("merchantId").item(0).getTextContent());
```

If you have more `merchantId` tags inside one node you just edit parameter in `.item()`